# Dynamics CRM - Server-Side Synchronization Issue

Tags: synchronization, server-side, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on Server-Side Synchronization in CRM online. I have created the Email Server Profile and set it to Use Impersonation. I associated Mailbox to same and I updated Email Configuration Settings, Process Email Using Server-Side Synchronization. However, in Mailbox when I Approve Email and click Test & Enable Mailbox, I get the below error as alert:

"*An impersonation error occurred in accessing the mailbox while receiving email. The mailbox abcMailbox has been disabled for receiving email and the owner of the associated email server profile aisemail has been notified.*"

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the steps to enable impersonation for the CRM User setup in the CRM Email Server profile as described in this blog article, specifically in step 2:  http://quantusdynamics.blogspot.com/2013/11/dynamics-crm-2013-configuring-exchange.html

The info below is taken from the blog post above.  Note that in the Get-ClientIdentityAccessServer command below that the -identity is the fully qualified domain name of your Microsoft CAS Server in Exchange and that in this part of the command, "Add-AdPermission -User "" ", that you would need to specify the CRM User that is setup in the CRM Email Server profile.

"
Exchange 2010
 New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name "" -Role:ApplicationImpersonation -User ""

For example: **New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Name "CRM ExServiceAcc" -Role:ApplicationImpersonation -User crm13.service**

Exchange 2007

**Get-MailboxServer "" | Add-AdPermission -User "" -AccessRights ExtendedRight -ExtendedRights ms-Exch-EPI-May-Impersonate, ms-Exch-EPI-Impersonation**

The second PowerShell command requires the Distinguished Name (DN) of the Microsoft Client Access Server (CAS).

To enable impersonation rights on a single Microsoft CAS server use the following command:

**Get-ClientAccessServer -Identity "" | Add-AdPermission -User "" -ExtendedRights ms-Exch-EPI-Impersonation**
"